# Duplicate Entry error while building APK

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application ... but when I try to build an APK I get this error

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/support/v7/util/AsyncListUtil$DataCallback.class

I can't seem to find a solution for it ... Here is my app-level gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.base29.alltimetoprecipes"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    //Here the magic Begins
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
//Here the magic Ends
    productFlavors {
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(include: ['picasso-2.5.2.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(include: ['httpmime-4.2.1.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

}
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks

UPDATE:

I have changed the versions of the dependencies ...

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(include: ['picasso-2.5.2.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(include: ['httpmime-4.2.1.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

}
```

Comment: Remove compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' dependencies because the package will also have all the other dependencies  like play-services-ads,play-services-identity etc..

Comment: you can use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'`

Comment: Please follow first comment

Comment: @AndanHM .. I had removed the said dependency ... but I got an analytics package not found error

Comment: @AndanHM ... should i remove these dependencies `play-services-ads,play-services-identity` instead of `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0` ... thoughts ?

Comment: If you are not using any google analytic  in your project you can remove...

Comment: I am using google analytics

Comment: Add this dependence compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
build.gradle

Comment: I have added the dependency you provided and removed the `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0` but now I am getting this error 
**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/util/MessageThreadUtil$SyncQueueItem.class**

Answer (score 0):

check your dependencies versions, you must have compatible versions put attention specially to com.google packages, must have same version like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

Comment: Are you saying that the dependencies versions that I have added specially the google player services ones ... are not correct ?

Comment: no no it is correct but some time its duplicate thats why it cause this error so you need to ad just one dependencies not multiple try to check it out one by one

Comment: first remove compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' one and build it then remove the other one if its not work

Comment: I am using google analytics and I think if I remove `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0` I will get an error ...

Comment: try it dont worry about error if you get error then try to remove the other one after that then buil it

Comment: I have removed the ad-services dependency and now I am getting this error **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/util/MessageThreadUtil$SyncQueueItem.class**